# PHP: Getting reference ID

Tags: php

How do I get the PHP reference ID, as is possible with the `var_dump` function:

```
// PHP 5.2.6
class Test {}

$test1 = new Test; var_dump($test1);
$test1b = $test1;  var_dump($test1b);
$test2 = new Test; var_dump($test2);
```

Resulting in:

```
object(Test)#1 (0) {}
object(Test)#1 (0) {}
object(Test)#2 (0) {}
```

See, `var_dump` can tell which references are equal without a straight-up comparison, and it prints their reference ID `#1` and `#2`.  How do *I* access that reference ID?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose a solution could be to use [`spl_object_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php) :

> This function returns a unique
>   identifier for the object. This id can
>   be used as a hash key for storing
>   objects or for identifying an object.

It's not a "simple" number like what you get with `var_dump`, but I suppose it's better than nothing...

For instance, with this portion of code, inspired from yours :

```
$test1 = new Test;
$test1b = $test1;
$test2 = new Test;

echo spl_object_hash($test1) . '<br />';
echo spl_object_hash($test1b) . '<br />';
echo spl_object_hash($test2) . '<br />';
```

I get this output :

```
000000002c836d1d000000006bfbdc77
000000002c836d1d000000006bfbdc77
000000002c836d1e000000006bfbdc77
```

Comment: Be aware that `spl_object_hash` may reuse hashes. From the documentation: "When an object is destroyed, its hash may be reused for other objects."

Answer (score 3):

I'm not proud, but this works:

```
ob_start();                                                                                                                                   
var_dump($test2);                                                                                                                             
$str = ob_get_contents();                                                                                                                     
ob_end_clean();                                                                                                                               

echo substr($str, strrpos($str, '#')+1, 1);
```

Comment: I like Pascal MARTIN's answer - nice idea.

Comment: As a side note, if the older object is garbage (or weakly reachable), the identifier may repeat. No matter the object reference ID or the hash, it might still be the same. Refer to this test. gist.github.com/SOF3/f472f849c57ade8ae5a8dc306ceba29b

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if you only want to get the reference id to compare 2 instances and make sure they're equal.
Should that be the case, you can use the '===' operator.

```
$test1 === $test1b will be true whereas $test1 === $test2 will be false.
```